# console still shows error after I delete the link to my AWS S3 JS file.

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I had an error in one of my js file that is stores in AWS' s3 object storage. 
I would link it there as such...

`"url": "https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/testForWebGL/29519.js",`

I have modified the url object to get the file locally

`"url": "29519.js",`

I will still get an error in the console for the the aws file. I tried deleting the file from aws, but than I get the error...

`index.js:2178 Script: https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/testForWebGL/29519.js failed to load`

I believe it has something to do with webpack caching since I am using `create-react-app`. I am also using google chrome extension `CORS` to allow cross-origin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you doubted the issue is with your local cache issue.

To see if the browser is caching:
eg: Can you check in an chrome incognito.

If you still see the older url in the chrome console.

Then it is the generated index that is old. In that case Clean build again.
eg: https://webpack.js.org/guides/output-management/#cleaning-up-the-dist-folder

Comment: Thank You for your reply. looks like it was the old index file.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you stop and restart the app with **npm start**

Comment: How would this help in your opinion?

Comment: Just from experience, I've had this problem with create-react-app caching and this has solved it for me before.